# Reusing Client TCP Connection for HTTP

Tags: http, sockets, tcp, reusability

Why can't I reuse a http client socket in a C web client, since I don't call `close(http_socket_fd)`? The first write/read to the socket file descriptor works perfectly well. Any/all successive reads return zero (hardly any error).

Basically, I don't want to keep recreating new client connection sockets to the same host for successive requests. Is it not possible in C to reuse an open client socket (which already has HTTP keep-alive enabled) for successive read/writes? It seems possible with Java http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-dev@jakarta.apache.org/msg04687.html

```
Example: (PSEUDO_CODE)
MANY_DOMAINS=30,000;
//initial connection
do{
  http_socket_to_domain_x=open(NEW_TCP_SOCKET_PER_DOMAIN);
  get(initial_url_path);
  read(http_socket_to_domain_x,initial_http_response);
} while(EACH_DOMAIN)
for(LIST_OF_URLS FROM EACH_DOMAIN);
  //successive connections - NO RECREATING TCP SOCKET!
do{
  get(another_url_path);
  read(http_socket_to_domain_x,another_http_response);
} while(EACH_URL_PER_DOMAIN)
//finally
close(http_socket_to_domain_x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read up on [**persistent HTTP/1.1 connections**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-8).

Comment: I use use HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive. I can even see thru netstat that the connections are kept open until timeout or explicitly closed by my client (not server). HTTP connections are hardly the problem. Perhaps it's gotta do with buffering also as in the case above involving Java.

Comment: If the next read returns zero, it doesn't matter if it's Java or anything else, the server (or a proxy somewhere) just closes the connection on you. Check what's going on on the wire with wireshark.

Comment: Nikolai, I have tested the web client even with my own web server and the client it still gets zero on reads after the first... notwithstanding that I can write successive requests without any problem - but never reading anything back! Thanks for the tip for wireshark though, i'll try it tonight.

Comment: Then you'll have to show us real code. There are too many details to get wrong.

Comment: Agreed.  It is too hard to figure out from such vague descriptions.  We need to see either actual code, or a log of the actual socket data being exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The server may be closing the connection. Are you sending HTTP/1.1 headers? See http://www.io.com/~maus/HttpKeepAlive.html for a bit more.

Comment: Yes I am Sir. I use use HTTP 1.1 with keep-alive. In fact the servers return back the appropriate response headers to confirm it. Am so sick of this! I cannot seem to get thru it and tis so critical that am able to.

Comment: Hrm, that sucks. Sorry I can't offer a whole lot more help.